# onetoone Mapping is not working in my spring boot rest application and json mysql

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

The one to one mapping is not working .here is my coding and json which posting from postman. the value is saving into mysql db  its only saving in my first db "pharmacy" and second Db is not saving that is Foreign key mapping. ;

```
json: {
    "pharmacyName":"test",
    "pharmacyaddress":{
   '     "pinCode":"600001",
          "address":"sample"

    }
}
```

First entity

```
@Entity @Table(name = "pharmacy") 
public class PharmacyEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "phrm_id")
    private Long id;
    private String pharmacyName;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "pharmacyEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
         fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
     private PharmacyDetailsEntity pharmacyaddress;
    public PharmacyDetailsEntity getPharmacyaddress() {
        return pharmacyaddress;
    }

    public void setPharmacyaddress(PharmacyDetailsEntity pharmacyaddress) {
        this.pharmacyaddress = pharmacyaddress;
        pharmacyaddress.setPharmacyEntity(this);
    }
```

//Getter & Setter
    }

---

### Second Entity;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "phrm_details")
public class PharmacyDetailsEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "phrm_dtls_id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "phrm_id", referencedColumnName = "phrm_id")
    private PharmacyEntity pharmacyEntity;

    @Column(name = "pin_code")
    private int pinCode;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String address;


}
```

This my @Restcontroller ,and am using JPA Repository for save and also using service and     service implementation

```
my controller is

@RequestMapping(value = "/savepharmacy", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")

public ResponseEntity<?> createPharmacy( @RequestBody PharmacyEntity pharmacyEntity) {
    try {

        PharmacyEntity ph = pharmacyservice.savePharmacy(pharmacyEntity);
        return new ResponseEntity<ProjectStatus>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<CustomErrorType>( HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping is correct.
Use EntityManager in Dao.

PharmacyDaoImpl:

```
@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public PharmacyEntity save(PharmacyEntity entity) {


    entityManager.persist(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

Input data :

{    "pharmacyName":"test",
    "pharmacyaddress":{
        "pinCode":"600001",
          "address":"sample" }
}

Response :

{    "id": 6,
    "pharmacyName": "test",
    "pharmacyaddress": {
        "id": 6,
        "pharmacyEntity": null,
        "pinCode": 600001,
        "address": "sample" }
}